# Get the field used in a NotesViewColumn using Java/SSJS

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino, xpages-ssjs

I have a handle to a NotesViewColumn and needs to know what field is used for that column (only fields are used, no formulas).

The column has "Display: Field" set and (naturally) just contains the field name.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try *getItemName()* method of *NotesViewColumn* class.

Hope this helps
Sven